# AS3: Simple way to get the frame number of a frame label

Tags: actionscript-3, frame

Is there a simple way to get the frame number of a frame label?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the [frame property](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/FrameLabel.html#frame) from the [FrameLabel](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/FrameLabel.html)

Comment: Links are broken.

Comment: This is an unhelpful answer.  You missed out the main part of the problem - how to get from knowing a frame label, e.g. "MyFrameLabel", to having a `FrameLabel` object to manipulate.  Once that bit is solved, getting the frame number from the object is trivial.

Comment: Also, I fixed the links.

Answer (score 7):

i haven't tested it but the following should work. the labels property of the Scene object is an Array of objects containing both the label & number of the frames.

```
 private function getFrameByLabel( frameLabel: String ):int
 {
       var scene:Scene = yourMovieClip.currentScene;

       var frameNumber:int = -1;

       for( var i:int ; i < scene.labels.length ; ++i )
       {
            if( scene.labels[i].name == frameLabel )
                frameNumber = scene.labels[i].frame;
       }

       return frameNumber;
  }
```

Comment: Note that you can also use `yourMovieClip.currentLabels`, in place of `scene.labels` if you are not using scenes (as all labels are in the current scope, in that situation).  You should also use this method if you only want to resolve labels that are in the current scene, rather than across all scenes in the movie.

Answer (score 0):

currentFrame return the current frame number of the movieclip.

```
import flash.display.FrameLabel;

var frameNumber:int = -1;
frameNumber = MyMovieClip.currentFrame;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all - it just gets the current frame number.  The OP wants to know how to get from "MyFrameLabel" to the frame number that it represents, for any given label.